# How to set Background image's Scretch and TileMode in Code behind?

Tags: c#, imagebrush

Using C#, how to set the Background image's TileMode and Stretch property?

> `StackPanel1.Background = new ImageBrush(new ....); // OK`
>   `StackPanel1.Background = Stretch.Uniform; //this doesn't work...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to set the property on the image brush itself.

```
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
StackPanel1.Background = imageBrush;
```